# Error: Cannot find module 'babel-core/register'

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have following error when trying to run my app on Heroku

```js
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-core/register'
2017-11-13T10:42:19.749689+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-11-13T10:42:19.749690+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-11-13T10:42:19.749691+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-11-13T10:42:19.749691+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-11-13T10:42:19.749692+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bootstrap.js:1:63)
2017-11-13T10:42:19.749692+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-11-13T10:42:19.749693+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-11-13T10:42:19.749694+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-11-13T10:42:19.749694+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-11-13T10:42:19.749695+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

My `package.json` file is:

```js
{
  "name": "birdbase",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "bell": "^8.7.0",
    "hapi": "^16.0.1",
    "hapi-auth-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.0",
    "knex": "^0.14.0",
    "mysql": "^2.14.1",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bootstrap.js"
  }
}
```

and my app is based on the following tutorial:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-a-restful-api-with-hapi-js
src: https://github.com/labsvisual/hapijs-birds-api

So `package.json` dependencies are same as in `devDependencies` (as was indicated on other Stack Overflow issues).

Any idea why there is an error?

Comment: Did you figure out the reason? I'm having a similar issue on Heroku.